# ConcurrentModificationException when drawing on SurfaceView?

Tags: android

Say I have an ArrayList of "blob" objects, which I cycle through and draw then onto the canvas.

```
     for (blob b:myBlobList)
     {
         canvas.drawCircle(b.X, b.Y, b.Size, paint);
     }
```

Also I have an onTouchListener that adds a new blob object whenever the surface is touched.

```
      if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
          myBlobList.add(new blob());
          myBlobList.get(myBlobList.size()-1).X = event.getX();
          myBlobList.get(myBlobList.size()-1).Y = event.getY();;
        }
```

Yet together they cause a ConcurrentModificationException error. What would be your suggestion, how should I fix that?

Simply adding

```
try{ ... } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {}
```

Makes the screen/canvas flicker when this exception happens and it goes happen a lot. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you add a new blob to your list while iterating over that list. One simple workaround would be to make a copy of the list before the loop. If you add items while iterating they will not be taken into account.

```
List<Blob> myBlobCopy = new ArrayList<Blob>(myBlobList); //copies the content
for (Blob b : myBlobCopy) {
    canvas.drawCircle(b.X, b.Y, b.Size, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` for your Blobs

Answer (score 1):

You need a second list myBlobList2 to use in onTouchListener then:

```
for (blob b:myBlobList){
         canvas.drawCircle(b.X, b.Y, b.Size, paint);
     }

myBlobList.addAll(myBlobList2);
myBlobList2.clear();
```

Still synchronization issues can occurs if:

- add object to myBlobList2 during myBlobList.addAll

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple for loop in place of forEach loop, and do iterating with your own index counter.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myBlobList.size(); i++){
   blob b = myBlobList.get(i);
   canvas.drawCircle(b.X, b.Y, b.Size, paint);
}
```

This [ConcurrentModificationException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) is occurring because of you are adding or deleting element from the ArrayList from other thread while forEach loop hold the Iterator when iterating through the ArrayList.